# Visual Studio & Tfs: Updating Source Control Status

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

When I launch a project on Visual Studio 2010, I have to wait 10 minutes while the "Updating Source Control Status" finishes at the bottom of the screen. Until this happens, Visual Studio is completely frozen.

I am connected via VPN, and I have enabled domain lookup for my tfs host. (http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/111260/VS-NET-2008-hangs-everytime-we-load-our-project-fr.aspx?tab=mostrecent)

I am not sure what else to do. Any ideas?

Comment: If you (or someone else) is local to the TFS server is it quicker? (Ie. is this a network performance – whether bandwidth or latency – or a server performance issue.)

Comment: Can you ping the server from your computer with the VPN activated and give us the latency returned?

Comment: hi! yes, the latency is: icmp_seq=0 ttl=125 time=79.625 ms
i managed to download entire source code within matter of seconds, i dont know why the update would take so long

Comment: I did a little looking around and I still see this is an issue without a resolution or I just have not found one yet. I constantly get "Updating Source Control Status". It's very annoying, that I have to wait 5 or more minutes to do anything in VS while this is happening.  (VS 2019 & DevOps in AZURE).

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to investigate is to enable tracing in devenv.exe (look at tf.exe.config and copy appropriate part to devenv.exe.config) and see what server calls are being made. I would recommend publishing results on msdn forum (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol) since TFS devs are monitoring it much closely than stackoverflow.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you use yourtfsserver.visualstudio.com and the site is down (for instance like it is right now due to an Azure storage disruption) VS may freeze up on you when you open a new source controlled project or randomly while your in a project even it it isn't in source control.